# Indexed file using WiX installer

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

I'm developing an installer that has some Windows and iOS features. Till now we don't have a specific installer for iOS, so we develop a regular Windows installer and then copy the iOS files to a Mac computer.

I have an iOS file that ahs the following details:

```
File type: iOS File
Attributes: AI
```

So I create my WiX file and harvest that specific file. When I install my package and look at this specific file details, they change a little bit... After installation it looks like this:

```
File type: iOS File
Attributes: A
```

It looses the `I` part, and it's not working. Following [this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/222954-file-attributes.html), the `A = Archived` and the `I=Indexed`, so my file is loosing its indexed part and not working.

Using WiX, it is being installed as a regular file:

```
<Component Id="cmp02966D4702C4F3FFBDF68F2A392C52F9" Directory="dir354E18D7AD4B72C9165606D96AE25DAB" Guid="2AC77104-550F-4E55-9CCC-95F89C8A6545">
     <File Id="filA16E0AF72FB4B00DBBD98D3274DD7C86" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.sourceFolder)bin\$(var.ios)\Assemblies\Packages.ios.framework\Versions\A\Packages.ios" />
</Component>
```

So... **Is there any way using WiX in which I can install my file and keep that index?**

NOTE: This file is an indexed file coming from another shortcut (which I have also problems to copy...).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the software stopped working because the `I` attribute is missing. Take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/775582/file-attributes-ai-any-clues) for more details.

The `A` attribute is set by the system to any file which has changed since the last backup operation. Hence, when you install a file to the target system, it is considered a new file there and obviously wasn't included in the most recent backup. It's natural that the `A` attribute is kept untouched.

The `I` attribute instructs the system not to include it into the system indexing list. And when you install a new file, the default behavior is not to excluded, as far as I understand. That's why the `I` attribute is missing on the installed file.

I think you should not try changing those attributes and let Windows do its job. Besides, investigate the failure of your iOS application deeper - I suspect it is not related to these attributes.